# How do I transpile aliased paths in TypeScript to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, tsc, tsconfig-paths

I have a TypeScript project that I am trying to transpile into executable JavaScript which makes use of path aliases. **This is required for the NPM package I am working on.**

For example here with importing a method from my `lib` directory without referencing it via relative paths:

```js
import { hexify } from '@lib/utils/conversion';
```

Usually I would use `tsconfig-paths` to register the path-aliases when running the app from the entry point with a command like `ts-node-dev --files -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts` or in production mode with `node -r ts-node/register/transpile-only -r tsconfig-paths/register ./dist/index.js`. But in this instance **I would like to successfully transpile it to JavaScript so that the compiler automatically translates the path aliases to the correct relative paths** therefore not needing to use `ts-node` and `tsconfig-paths` to successfully run the JavaScript code.

My `tsconfig.json` file looks like this for some additional context:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@middleware/*": ["src/middleware/*"],
      "@services/*": ["src/services/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["src/routes/*"],
      "@controllers/*": ["src/controllers/*"],
      "@exchanges/*": ["src/api/exchanges/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
      "@api/*": ["src/api/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["src/lib/*"],
      "@app": ["src/app/index.ts"],
      "@singleton/*": ["src/singleton/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["junk"]
}
```

However when building this project, my NPM package cannot make sense of my path aliases, is there something I can do about this to make my NPM package work or should I just change all my TypeScript imports using aliases to instead use relative paths like this example below:

```js
import { hexify } from '../lib/utils/conversion.ts'
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no way to do this as part of a `tsc` build.

There are a number of modules out there that will do the task for you, such as `ts-alias`. Indeed, a search on npm for "typescript path alias" gives 66 such modules: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=typescript%20path%20alias